# Android Studio 0.8.9 How to change buttons shape?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've seen most of post @ stackoverflow and i've done as told.

Create new xml (tried a few different samples)
But i can't change the background in activity xml, it does not want to find "@drawable/shape"

I have the new xml in right folder and I'm struggling with it since this morning. I'd be more than glad to see some help ;)

Sorry, I've got it like that:

```
    '
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/chest"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textSize="23sp"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/maxWagi"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/maxWagi"
    android:background="@drawable:button_shape"'
```

//  <----- if I change it to some #color it's working just fine.

and my xml button_shape is in app\src\main\res\xml\ (android studio put it over there by itself)  I even added manually drawable folder like in most tutorials but it does not change anything

Comment: well,, you have told `right folder` and everythingis right. then why is there some problem. :-/ show us something to see what where goes wrong

Comment: Sorry I'm quite fresh in here.A little bit better now?

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax mistake. Your background should be `@drawable/button_shape` instead of `@drawable:button_shape`. Also put in a `drawable` folder in `res`.

Comment: Thanks yes I've already changed the syntax. But creating new folder called drawable worked just fine! Thanks a lot and again huge sorry for the messy topic.